# How to implement following c# expression tree usage?

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

Assuming I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

How can I or if it's even possible to implement a method with the usage of Expression Tree such that it would look like the following?

```
Dictionary<string, object> someDictionary = GetDictionary();
Person person = new Person();
person.Set(someDictionary, "someKey", p => p.Name, value => Transform(value));
```

Such that `person.Name` will be set by `Transform(value)` where `value` is provided by the dictionary?

I have started a signature of an extension method like

```
public static void Set<TValue>(
    this Person person, 
    IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, 
    string key, 
    Expression<Func<Person, TValue>> selector, 
    Expression<Func<object, TValue>> transformer)
```

But does not have much clue on how to implement it.
Any helps are welcome.  Thanks.

I have something like the following:

```
public static void Set<TValue>(this Person person, IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key, Expression<Func<Person, TValue>> selector, Expression<Func<object, TValue>> transformer)
{
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
    {
        return;
    }

    // more logic to manipulate 'value'...

    var parameterExpression = (ParameterExpression) ((MemberExpression) selector.Body).Expression;
    var delegateExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<Person>>(
        Expression.Assign(selector.Body, transformer.Body), parameterExpression
    );

    delegateExpression.Compile()(person);
}
```

But I'm unable to figure out on how to pass the `value` to the `transformer`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but you probably want to look at LinqKit http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Comment: Why do you require the parameters to be expressions? Since you have `p => p.Name` as an expression, why can't you simply do it with `(p, value) => p.Name = Transform(value)` directly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the answer. Anyone can tell me whether it's legit?

```
public static void Set<TValue>(this Person person, IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key, Expression<Func<Person, TValue>> selector, Expression<Func<object, TValue>> transformer)
{
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
    {
        return;
    }

    var parameterExpression = selector.Parameters.Concat(transformer.Parameters);
    var delegateExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<Person, object>>(
        Expression.Assign(selector.Body, transformer.Body), parameterExpression
    );

    delegateExpression.Compile()(person, value);
}
```